# How to insert Page numbers in Hindu Numerals in Arabic Context?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have set the Numerals in "Options --> Advanced" to "Context". I changed the language to Arabic in my document. When I type numbers in the document body, the numbers are displayed in Arabic numbers (Hindu) [which is correct], but when I insert Page Numbers, tho I'm still in the Arabic context the numbers are displayed in English numbers (ie 1,2,3). How can I fix this and display the page numbering in Arabic as well?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously this is a bug in Office 2016.

You may give this workaround a try:

Go to the Quick Access Toolbar at the top left (if English Word) of your Word document and click the down arrow. From the list, choose "More Commands". Under "Choose commands from:" in the window that opens, choose "All Commands". From the column below look for "Rtl Run" and double-click it to add it to the other column, then click OK. You'll notice that a circle appears in the Quick Access Toolbar. Now click any number in the list to highlight them all, then click that circle in the Quick Access Toolbar. This should make the list numbers Hindi.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm in Office 365.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out why this problem is happening and managed to solve it. See video
https://youtu.be/egZflseLdRU

Steps:

1. Ensure the page number is RTL.
2. Highlight the page number
3. Right click and edit field
4. Click Page
5. Show field code
6. Replace whatever you see with this code PAGE HINDI
7. Confirm your code.
   That's all.

Answer (score 1):

After inserting `Page Number` change text direction, while you're editing the footer, from `left-to-right` to `right-to-left` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right <kbd>Shift</kbd>)
The numbers should be represented in Hindi after you do that, worked for me (MS Word 2013).

Answer (score 0):

It is because your paragraph direction is still Left-to-Right which is the “Context” and preferred choice for the English (Arabic numeral) users. To display Hindi numerals in page numbering which is the standard for Arabic text, you need to change the paragraph direction of your page numbering to Right-to-Left direction. To do so, follow one of the two ways as described below:

**Way 1**
1.  Make sure that you choose “Context” in “Options --> Advanced" to "Context".
2.  Edit your page number in the Header of Footer by double clicking the page number area (any number).
3.  Put your cursor exactly on the page number.
4.  As your cursor is on page number, go to Page Layout on the ribbon of your Microsoft Word (i.e., 2013)
5.  Edit the Paragraph section. Under the General in the Indents and Spacing tab, look for Direction, and tick “Right-to-Left”. 
That is all. The number will change to Hindi.
If you make this change on an Odd number, you may need to do the same thing on an Even number.

**Way 2:**
Follow step 1-3 as described above
4. Go to Home on your Ribbon and simply click Right-to-Left Text Direction button while your cursor is on page number.